# Samples required by Mann-Kendall Test vs Modified Mann-Kendall Test

Tags: autocorrelation, test-for-trend

Does the modified Mann-Kendall test by Hamed and Rao [1] require more samples than the original Mann-Kendall test?  For example, the Visual Sample Plan (VSP) tool [2] calculates the number of samples required by the original Mann-Kendall test to meet certain requirements.  To enter the requirements into VSP, navigate to "Sampling Goals">"Detect a Trend">"Residuals not required to be normally distributed">"No Seasonality".  A dialog box appears having a "Calculate" button on the Mann-Kendall tab.  Press the "Calculate" button to direct VSP to "determine the number of sampling periods necessary to detect change."  Is that calculated number also applicable to the modified Mann-Kendall test?

[1] https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-1694(97)00125-X
[2] https://vsp.pnnl.gov/

Comment: Relevant to attempting an answer: How many observations do you believe are required for the Mann Kendall - and on what basis is that number necessary?

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.